# If $S$ is simple a module over a ring $R$ which is noetherian, hereditary and every simple module is injective, then $S$ is finitely presentated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a left noetherian and left hereditary ring , also suppose every simple left module $M$ over $R$ is injective. Prove that a simple left module $S$ over $R$ is finitely presentated. So Im supposed to find and exact sequence $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} R \to  \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m} R  \to S \to 0$$ where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Some of my ideas are that as I already know that as $R$ is left hereditary then $p.d(S) \leq 1$ which is somehow why this exact sequence make sense.  Also, as $S$ is simple over $R$, then $S$ is cyclic which means it is finitely generated which means $S$ can be covered by copies of $R$, also here I want to use is $R$ Noetherian to get an injection into the direct sum of copies of $R$ which cover $S$. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you know that "finitely generated" and "finitely presented" coincide for Noetherian rings??? And simple modules are always finitely generated... The hypotheses you included seem a bit overblown.

Comment: You are right, originally I was trying to prove the module $S$ with all this hypotheses was  someting called "clasical partial tilting module" and I already used two of these hypotheis still havent use the fact $R$ noetherian.

Comment: I don't mean to sound critical, but it seems highly irregular to me that you're studying things that advanced (I have no idea what it is) without seeing how this other elementary thing works... I suppose that is one way to learn easy and hard stuff at the same time, though!  Just wonder if you aren't throwing yourself too far in the deep end.

Comment: Yes,  I didnt have chance to take more basic course in modules in the past semesters and the only algebra courses available this semester where this more advanced courses in modules. I get your point, so far I have liked module theory a lot but still reading and learning some of the basics by checking out first chapters of Kasch book to grasp more of the basics.

Comment: I know of Kasch's book, but I've never had a chance to look at it. There are so many directions to go. Good luck anyhow!

Comment: Thanks !Any advice on how  to  properly learn module theory or the best book in your opinion?@rschwieb

Comment: Can't go wrong with T.Y. Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings*.  It's has an enormous range of subject matter and difficulty, and provides jump-off points for a lot of advanced studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is simple, it is cyclic, and you have a homomorphism $R\to S$.

Since $R$ is Noetherian, the kernel is finitely generated.

This, AFAICT proves $S$ is finitely presented, without any of the other assumptions.  You can then get your sequence by mapping onto the kernel with a free module.

In fact, one should also note that *every finitely generated left $R$ module over a left Noetherian ring $R$ is automatically finitely presented.*

Comment: Thanks! @rschwieb